# Selection sort with arraylists?

Tags: java, arraylist, selection-sort

I have to adapt selection sort for a school thing. The purpose is to return ranking of players with winners coming first, etc. Equally ranked players should be listed in the same order as they occur in the tournament list.

```
public ArrayList<Player> ranking() {
    ArrayList<Player> result = new ArrayList<Player>();
    // Supply this code!
    return result;
```

Now heres my attempt at adapting selection sort

```
    int smallInt = 0;
    int j=0;
    int smallIntIndex = 0;      

    for(int i=1;i<players.size();i++){
        smallInt = result.get(i-1).totalScore();
        smallIntIndex = i-1;
        for(j=i;j<players.size();j++){
            if(result.get(j).totalScore()<smallInt){
                smallInt = result.get(j).totalScore();
                smallIntIndex = j;                    
            }
        }
        int temp = result.get(smallIntIndex).totalScore();
        result.set(smallIntIndex, result.get(i-1));
        result.set(i-1, temp);
    }
    return result;
```

And the only line that gives me error is the very last

```
result.set(i-1, temp); //The method set(int, Player) in the type 
                       //ArrayList<Player> is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Is most of the adaptation correct? ANY HELP APPRECIATED. Thanks

p.s. please don't suggest comparators or stuff like that, that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: The error says it all really. Change variable `temp` to be of type `Player` instead of `int`.

Comment: The outer loop must start from index `0`, **NOT** `1`, and must end at `players.size() - 1`, the inner loop must start from index `i+1`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

- you are initializing an empty `result` array, but the algorithm works on existing arrays by swapping elements. You must initialize `result` with the values of `players`

  ```
  List<Player> result = new ArrayList<Player>(players);
  ```
- variable `temp` must be of type `Player` instead of `int`

  ```
  Player temp = result.get(smallIntIndex);
  ```
- the outer loop must start from index `0`, **not** `1`
- the outer loop must end at `players.size() - 1`
- the inner loop must start from index `i+1`
- you swap elements every time in the outer loop, this is **not** correct. Only swap them when a new minimum is found

The corrected code:

```
public ArrayList<Player> ranking() {
    List<Player> result = new ArrayList<Player>(players);
    int smallInt = 0;
    int j=0;
    int smallIntIndex = 0;      

    for(int i=0;i<result.size() - 1;i++){
        smallInt = result.get(i).totalScore();
        smallIntIndex = i;
        for(j=i+1;j<result.size();j++){
            if(result.get(j).totalScore()<smallInt){
                smallInt = result.get(j).totalScore();
                smallIntIndex = j;                    
            }
        }

        if (i != smallIntIndex) {
            Player temp = result.get(smallIntIndex);
            result.set(smallIntIndex, result.get(i));
            result.set(i, temp);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**EDIT:** You ask that the sorted results must go into a separate `results` array, which is initially empty. Here's a way to do it:

```
public ArrayList<Player> ranking() {
    List<Player> result = new ArrayList<Player>();
    int smallInt = 0;
    int j=0;
    int smallIntIndex = 0;      

    for(int i=0;i<players.size() - 1;i++){
        smallInt = players.get(i).totalScore();
        smallIntIndex = i;
        for(j=i+1;j<players.size();j++){
            if(players.get(j).totalScore()<smallInt){
                smallInt = players.get(j).totalScore();
                smallIntIndex = j;                    
            }
        }

        if (i != smallIntIndex) {
            Player player = players.get(smallIntIndex);

            result.add(player);
            players.set(smallIntIndex, players.get(i));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Reference: [Wikipedia's article on selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Implementation)

Comment: Hmm. `result` is just created when the method is called, so does that mean it holds the same values as the ArrayList `players` which are then sorted? Should values be inserted into `result`, or maybe lines like `if(result.get(j).totalScore()<smallInt)` shouldnt include `result`? Or am just wrong and `result` contains the same values as `players`?

Comment: Im afraid its not actually sorting them. its just returning the same values in the same order they were entered. But its not giving me a compilation error, so thats good.

Comment: Oh wait, how are you displaying them? Im using `System.out.println(T.ranking());` and it outputs `[]` ? How to properly display it?

Comment: `ArrayList<Player> winners2 = T.ranking();
  for(int i = 0; i <winners2.size(); i++)
   System.out.println(T.ranking());` . Like that? Sorry, im not quite sure I understood what you meant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127434/discussion-between-genti-saliu-and-rob-bor).

Comment: Its ouputting garbage values. Like `comp125.Player@6d06d69c` and
 `comp125.Player@7852e922`

Comment: Yeah, but thats all Im getting now. Even if i use your first solution including `ArrayList<Player> result = new ArrayList<Player>(players);` those garbage values is all Im getting.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i <winners2.size(); i++) { 
     System.out.println(winners2.get(i).totalScore()); 
}`

Comment: Yeah, forgot the totalScore part, haha. Im an idiot. Thanks for everything

Answer (score 0):

If you change

> int temp = result.get(smallIntIndex).totalScore();

to

> Player temp = result.get(smallIntIndex);

the program will compile.

The original code tries to insert `Persons`'s `totalScore` into the list, instead of `Person`.